# Realistic chain simulation in p2.js

Tags: javascript, simulation, physics

I'm trying to create a simulation of chains using [p2js](https://github.com/schteppe/p2.js) but I'm having trouble with the links stretching.

[image: Sample of hanging chains]

The four chains on the left have lighter links than those on the right, but the weights on the ends are the same (bigger box means heavier). Note that the chains stretch more the heavier the load, and less if the links are heavier.

Can someone explain why the weight of the links affects the stretching of the constraint and suggest a way that I can reduce the stretching to as little as possible. It seems odd that heavier links stretch less - I'd expect them to stretch more as the total weight is heavier...

Fiddling with the `stiffness` and `relaxation` gives better results but still noticeable stretch. And the chains tend to blow apart quite easily as discussed in the question [What causes the joints of a physics engine to tear?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374145/what-causes-the-joints-of-a-physics-engine-to-tear).

An example fiddle is at https://jsfiddle.net/yew0ux24/2/.

(PS I tried creating a new tag `p2.js` but didn't have enough reputation to do so).